# Ivy : dependency between 2 dependencies

Tags: ivy

I am looking for a way to declare "a dependency between 2 dependencies".

For instance, in my module, I have in ivy.xml the following lines :

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency org="org.slf4j" name="slf4j-api" rev="${slf4japiversion}"/>
    <dependency org="ch.qos.logback" name="logback-classic" rev="1.0.13" conf="test->default"/>
</dependencies>
```

My problem is that logback-classic 1.0.13 depends on slf4j-api 1.7.5 and my module depends on 1.6.6 (value of slf4japiversion).

I can't change slf4japiversion but in the future it could be upgraded by someone else.

Is there a way to declare the dependency on logback to retrieve the version compatible with my slf4j-api version ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify an override directive to force resolution to a particular version of a dependency:

```
   <dependencies>
      <dependency org="org.slf4j" name="slf4j-api" rev="1.6.6" conf="compile->default"/>
      <dependency org="ch.qos.logback" name="logback-classic" rev="1.0.13" conf="runtime->default"/>

      <override org="org.slf4j" module="slf4j-api" rev="1.6.6"/>
   </dependencies>
```

A word of warning, when downgrading dependencies. If logback uses a feature only supported by version 1.7.5 then the solution will not work. It's far more likely a library is backwardly compatible.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So there is no way to automagically select the logback version compatible with my slf4j version ?

Comment: @Ekans You can look at the logback dependencies and go back in time. The Maven Central website is really useful for this (http://search.maven.org/). Wouldn't it be a lot simpler to just upgrade your code to be compatible with the latest version of SLF4J?

Comment: Yes it would be easier but this version is fixed by another project out of my control. And sometimes the slf4j version is upgraded without notification. So, except manually, I have no other way to retrieve the right version of logback ?

Comment: @Ekans Is this actually broken? The default approach is to use the latest requested version, this is built on the assumption that new versions would be backwardly compatible. If they're not your problems are deeper because you can't have two copies of the same class on the classpath (well you can, but only one is active)

Comment: @Ekans That's a new question! and it'll be a duplicate. I'm pretty certain it was asked before.

Comment: Ok. I found other subjects close to mine and your solution is the best compromise.